# Remove objects from ObservableObject

Tags: swiftui, combine, observableobject

Two `ViewModels`, one is a store of `roles` containing `skills`:

```
final class RolesStore: ObservableObject {
  @Published var roles: [Role] = []
.....
```

A role model is:

```
struct Role: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    var name: String
    var skills: [Skill]
}
```

The other `ViewModel` is a store of `skills`:

```
final class SkillStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var skills: [Skill] = []
.....
```

The following shows what i want to do, remove a skill from `SkillStore` (handy), and also have the deleted skill automatically removed from any `role` that happen to have the skill in the `RoleStore`:

[image: remove handy skill]

As you can see, removing the skill `handy` doesn't remove it from the role `Ansatt`.
I am not sure how to do that, so I prepared a Xcode Playground anyone can clone from Github: https://github.com/imyrvold/roleSkills

There must be a way of having `SkillStore` having a dependency on the skills in `SkillStore` or is there no other way than looping through all the roles and remove the skill from all the roles that have this skill?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this, when I remembered that a class could subscribe to changes in another class with the magic of `Combine`. So if I could have `RoleStore` class subscribe to changes in `SkillStore`, then `RoleStore` could update and remove the skill in its roles when a user deletes a skill.

To do that, `RolesStore` needs to have a reference to `SkillStore`:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

var skillStore = SkillStore(skills: MySkills.skills())
var roleStore = RoleStore(roles: MyRoles.roles(), skillStore: skillStore)

struct ModelsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var skillStore: SkillStore
    @ObservedObject var roleStore: RoleStore
....
```

`SkillStore` is updated with a `PassthroughSubject` that will send the deleted skill (`deletedPublisher`):

```
import Foundation
import Combine

public final class SkillStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var skills: [Skill] = [] {
        didSet {
            let oldSkills = Set(oldValue)
            let uniqueSet = oldSkills.subtracting(self.skills)
            if let deletedSkill = uniqueSet.first {
                deletedPublisher.send(deletedSkill)
            }
        }
    }
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    let deletedPublisher = PassthroughSubject<Skill, Never>()

    public init(skills: [Skill]) {
        self.skills = skills
    }

    public func delete(skills: [Skill]) {
        for skill in skills {
            if let index = self.skills.firstIndex(where: { $0 == skill }) {
                self.skills.remove(at: index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and finally `RoleStore` removes the deleted skill from all the roles that have this skill:

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import SwiftUI

public final class RoleStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var roles: [Role] = []
    @ObservedObject var skillStore: SkillStore
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    public init(roles: [Role], skillStore: SkillStore) {
        self.roles = roles
        self.skillStore = skillStore
        self.skillStore.deletedPublisher.sink { skill in
            for roleIndex in self.roles.indices {
                let skills = self.roles[roleIndex].skills.filter { $0 != skill }
                self.roles[roleIndex].skills = skills
            }
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

I have updated the Playground with the changes.